# ï»¿ sent with POST header

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, character-encoding, utf-8

we are using an payment extension that sends a POST response if the transaction was successful. For some reason the string contains some none UTF-8 characters.

The response looks like this `ï»¿OK` The right resposne is `OK`

I have the same payment extension in other shop (different customer and server) and there the extension is working perfectly.

Does anyone have any experience what could be causing this change in the response?  I talked with the developers of the extension but they say it has to be something on the server side. I checked the encoding on server and its **UTF-8**.

I checked the response with Chrome extension Postman and the response comes without the strange characters - "OK".

I have no idea left what could be causing this change in response string. Where could be the `ï»¿` generated?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently seeing `ï»¿` is the [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). This happens when you display a UTF-8 response without the correct encoding. Depending on how you display the response you might be able to force UTF-8 decoding in your browser by adding `header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');` before your output or an `echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';`

In summary: I don't think there is an issue with the response itself just the way the content is interpreted.